# PHP function to scrape first image

Tags: php, image, wordpress, tumblr

In a Wordpress blog I'm using the following function to scrape the page (single post view) and find the first image and, if none is found, to use a default image:

```
    function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "http://custome_url_for_default_image.png";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

I tried to paste it as is in a Tumblr theme, but encounter some problems (it does not load as a PHP function). Surely I’m missing something. If anyone has an idea for troubleshooting this I’ll be glad to try it.

Thanks,

P.

Comment: Yes sorry: web scraping, fetching, harvesting... I also realized I need the opening and closing tag for a PHP script, but adding them didn't make the function work either.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this would be to [avoid using regexes to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Try using DOMDocument:

```
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($post->post_content);
    $imgTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if ($imgTags->length > 0) {
        $imgElement = $imgTags->item(0);
        return $imgElement->getAttribute('src');
    } else {
        return 'http://custome_url_for_default_image.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the exact strategy I would use to solve this problem too. The DOMDocument makes it possible to very elegantly solve this problem. Bravo.

Comment: It sure seems to be cleaner and I’m glad to learn about the “orthodox” or correct way of coding such a function. I must still be doing something wrong though because the code does not work as a PHP code: part of it actually appears on my website (it’s visible) even though I used the opening and closing PHP tags and made sure to include the function in the `<body>`. I’ll do more test and try to figure it out. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: [UPDATE] Apparently (if I’m not mistaking) Tumblr’s theme do not support PHP code... My bad on this one. Although there could be a workaround: hosting the PHP script on a self-hosted server and calling it within the theme. But that’s all new ball game. Thanks for the support!